# phonegap save image from url to album

Tags: javascript, android, image, cordova

How to save image from url to album using phonegap for android

my code is:

```
<a href="#" onclick="saveToPhotoAlbum('https://build.phonegap.com/images/icon.png', true);">Click to save!</a>
```

Comment: What is the problem exactly? Is there an error message?

Comment: I used this <a href="#" onclick="saveToPhotoAlbum('https://build.phonegap.com/images/icon.png', true);">Click to save!</a> but not working!
i want when click on image .. save it to album

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use file transfer plugin

[File transfer plugin link](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.3.0/cordova_file_file.md.html#FileTransfer)

```
function saveToPhotoAlbum(myuri)
{
var fileTransfer = new FileTransfer();
var uri = encodeURI(myuri);
var filePath="cdvfile://localhost/persistent/myImageFolder/myImage.jpg";

fileTransfer.download(
    uri,
    filePath,
    function(entry) {
        console.log("download complete: " + entry.fullPath);
    },
    function(error) {
        console.log("download error source " + error.source);
        console.log("download error target " + error.target);
        console.log("upload error code" + error.code);
    },
    false,
    {
        headers: {
            "Authorization": "Basic dGVzdHVzZXJuYW1lOnRlc3RwYXNzd29yZA=="
        }
    }
);
}

<a href="#" onclick="saveToPhotoAlbum('https://build.phonegap.com/images/icon.png');">Click to save!</a>
```

Comment: how to use it? tell me please.

Comment: i want save image to phone photos album

Comment: What do you think photo album is? Or which photo album you are talking about? Android gallery is just a view to show the images in phone's memory. If you save images in phone's internal/external storage it will show inside Android photo gallery. (You may need to refresh the gallery) `Filepath` is the path where you want to save the picture. You can save the picture anywhere in phone's storage. You can save the photo in your own folder, or you can save it in the picture folder etc. @user3492381

Comment: Don't know. try yourself.